fix broken apt xdg-desktop-portal-kde and pipewire
my apt is completely broken because apt xdg-desktop-portal-kde is requiered by plasma and apt xdg-desktop-portal-kde requier pipewire.
I tryed uninstalling pipewire by force because it was broken but when I uninstalled xdg-desktop-portal-kde now its over.
How can I fix my apt and kde distro ?

Please include relevant error messages (from sudo apt upgrade) in your question. Thanks.

Please also mention your Ubuntu version.
